# ¿Cómo sucedió la evolucion de la palabra deprecar (ES) y deprecate (EN)?

Tags: historia

¿Cómo ha evolucionado tan diferente la palabra deprecar (ES) y deprecate (EN)?

La palabra es casi la misma pero tiene diferentes significados:
En la RAE se define [deprecar](https://dle.rae.es/deprecar):

> 1. tr. Rogar, pedir, suplicar con eficacia o instancia. U. t. c. prnl.

En el Oxford Dictionary [deprecate](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deprecate?q=deprecate):

> **​deprecate something** (formal) to feel and express strong disapproval
>   of something ​
>
> **be deprecated (computing)** (of a software feature) to be
>   considered outdated and best avoided, even though you can still use
>   it, usually because it has been replaced with a newer feature A number
>   of features have been deprecated in the latest version of the
>   software.

En el Oxford Dictionary si menciona su origen como:

> early 17th cent. (in the sense ‘pray against’): from Latin deprecat-
>   ‘prayed against (as being evil)’, from the verb deprecari, from de-
>   (expressing reversal) + precari ‘pray’.

Otro hilo sobre el tema es:
[¿Cómo se puede decir que algo está "deprecated" en castellano?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23098/c%c3%b3mo-se-puede-decir-que-algo-est%c3%a1-deprecated-en-castellano/31378#31378) pero no es lo mismo saber cómo traducir que entender cómo ha evolucionado de forma diferente.

Comment: La pregunta parece interesante, pero no sé si vamos a poder responder a la parte de la evolución de la palabra en inglés, dado que se sale del ámbito del sitio. Para comparaciones entre diferentes idiomas tal vez sea mejor preguntar en [Linguistics.SE], pero tendrás que traducir la pregunta al inglés.